# Mdframed as Chapter Title

Tags: chapters, mdframed

I am trying to compile exercises into on sheet of paper each, and treat the Exercises as Chapter. [image]

And then I will

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item Hi Mom
\item Hi Dad
\item Hi there
\end{enumerate}
```

inside the box. 
My ability is just

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mdframed}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}
\chapter{hmmm}
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\end{enumerate}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And the question is...? I am pretty sure that `mdframed` provides numbered boxes and there's no need to 'misuse' the `\chapter` command for this. Apart from the fact, there's no `\chapter` macro in `article` ;-)

Comment: ah! Right! Thanks for pointing out \chapter in article!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question requested `mdframed`, but I am more familiar with `tcolorbox` that's why used that package

This does not really use the `\chapter` command, but the chapter counter (if really needed) and makes an entry to the `ToC`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,mdframed}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz}


\newtcolorbox[use counter=chapter]{exercisebox}[2][]{%
  before={\cleardoublepage\thispagestyle{empty}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#2}},
  enhanced,
  attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm},
  title={\chaptername\ \thetcbcounter~#2},
  breakable,
  sharp corners,
  colback=white,
  colbacktitle={blue!50!white},
  #1,
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{exercisebox}{hmmm}
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\end{enumerate}
\end{exercisebox}

\begin{exercisebox}{Another question}
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\end{enumerate}
\end{exercisebox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear complainers (and there will be some, I bet): Of course using a separate counter instead of `chapter` will be much better, but the logical design request is by the O.P. and not my invention